# How to remove this pipe that appears to be glued in?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe

My basement utility sink has been draining slowly, so I removed the P trap looking for a clog. It was totally clean so the issue seems to be further down the line and beyond my comfort zone.

Anyways, while doing so one of the pipes seemed to get cracked and some holes in it and the old seals weren't sealing well, so I figured I would replace the whole P trap right away (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-Heavy-Duty-1-1-2-in-to-1-1-4-in-Plastic-Adjustable-Diameter-P-Trap-with-Reducing-Washer-HDC9682/315713959). The problem is I'm not sure how to remove this pipe that seems to be glued in with some sort of blue adhesive. Any advice would be appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The blue stuff is a thread sealant. Tru Blu, for instance. Heat is the usual advice for breaking the seal (if you can't just force it). Focus the heat on the trash component if you use heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already removed a **slip joint nut** (which someone who doesn't understand slip joints slathered some sealant on, pointlessly. Those threads don't seal, they just hold the tapered sealing washer between the trap tail tube and the tapered seat of the trap adapter.) We can see the nut backed up to the Union nut on the trap tail.

That means the joint, however stuck, is a slip joint, so it should pull straight out. The slip joint washer may be a bit stuck, and the two metal pipes may have corroded a bit to make it difficult, but pull straight out is the way. Perhaps some mallet action on the bent section of the trap arm would persuade movement.

Save the nut, and buy a new slip joint washer for the next trap. The fitting with the blue goop on it it a trap adapter, having a slip joint on the blue side and female pipe threads on the opposite side.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I knew it should pull straight out, and I also thought the glue seemed to be inappropriately used. My issue is it's very stuck and I can't seem to get it out. I tried some mallet action and part of the bad pipe broke off. 

Any other thoughts for how to get the old pipe out?

Comment: Up[date: The pipe ended up breaking off so now I'm essentially just digging out the rest of it that's still inside by wedging a screwdriver between the old pipe and the new pipe to crush it so it eventually comes out.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I have watched a lot of (professional!) plumbing videos on YouTube when I was bored, and "dig the pieces of a broken pipe/coupler out of another coupler/pipe you want to preserve" is absolutely a staple of those videos.

Comment: Give me polypropylene traps and PVC or ABS plumbing over metals any time...